# Windows .Bat file behave differently when executed from command window and by double clicking on the bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Windows .Bat file behave differently when executed from command window and by double clicking on the bat file. This is my file:

```
ECHO ON
del activity_ftp.log
cd D:\My_Test
IF EXIST united_ops*.csv (
for %%i in (united_ops*.csv) do (
set size=0
set /A size=%%~zi
echo %%i,%size%,397312,624640 > D:\My_Test\activity_ftp.log
)
)
```

When I run this by opening command window and calling it,

Comment: Could you please edit your question so the batch file contents is formatted as source code?

Comment: What is the difference that you notice?

Comment: Looks like you are on the wrong drive letter ... Add `D:` after `ECHO ON` and move `cd D:\My_Test` one line up.

Comment: "Runs differently" means nothing if you don't say what the difference is between them. "My dog looks different" - different than what? What he looked like earlier today? Than the neighbor's dog? Than the steak on your plate? Than your car? Please remember that we can't see your screen or read your mind from here - you need to provide enough information for us to be able to help you. :-)

Comment: This strange behaviour really happens. I have a simplified example - try `for /f "tokens=1-5*" %1 in ('Vol') do set vlab%2=%6`. This command should extract Volume name to the variable named "vlabin". It works only when entered in a CMD window. When run in a BAT file the output says that "in was unexpected at this time.", however this message is visible BEFORE the command quote (not AFTER as error messages normally appears).

Answer (score 3):

There are some issues in your code.
`cd d:\My_test` will only work if you are on `D:`, you could use `cd /d` or `pushd` here.

`echo ...%size%` doesn't work, as it's expands when the for block is parsed not when it's executed.

The `if exist` seems to be redundant, as the `for %%i in ( united_ops*.csv)` only expands if any file exists.

```
ECHO ON
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
del activity_ftp.log
pushd D:\My_Test
for %%i in (united_ops*.csv) do (
    set size=0
    set /A size=%%~zi         
    echo %%i,!size!,397312,624640 > D:\My_Test\activity_ftp.log
)
```

Comment: After I did the changes as per Jeb's suggestion, it is working as I expected it to. Thank you Jeb for the solution.

Comment: "setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion" was the solution to a similar problem I had.  Just had to also switch variables to use ! instead of %

Answer (score 0):

Building on jeb's answer.

1) Your FOR loop may iterate through many files that match your pattern. But you use the overwrite mode of file redirection. Each found file will over-write the output for the prior file. Your final output file will never have more than one line. You could change to the append mode using `>>`, but there is a better way. It is faster to enclose the entire loop in parentheses and redirect once in overwrite mode using `>`.

2) You are setting size to 0, then setting it to the file size, and then you don't use it after the line is echoed. I suspect you don't need the variable at all, so you don't need delayed expansion.

3) The file you delete at the top does not include the path information, so it may not be deleting from the correct folder. Even if it were, it is unnecessary since you are redirecting in overwrite mode anyway.

4) Instead of changing the current directory you could include the path in the FOR statement.

```
ECHO ON
>"D:\My_Test\activity_ftp.log" (
  for %%i in ("d:\My_Test\united_ops*.csv") do (
    echo %%~nxi,%%~zi,397312,624640
  )
)
```